# React Js: export problems '(possible exports: default)'

Tags: reactjs

Hello i'm not sure what i'm doing wong i keep getting this error

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Workers/Workers.js 17:35-42
export 'Sidebar' (imported as 'Sidebar') was not found in '../../components/Sidebar/index' (possible exports: default)
```

**Stucture**:

[image: Structure]

**Import**:
[image: Import]
**Export**:
[image: Export]

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
import Sidebar from'./components/Sidebar/index'
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing something alittle different. Inside my Components Folder, I will list all my components, and when Im done, I will add an index.jsx file. And inside the index.jsx file I'll list all the components inside there.

```
export { default as Navbar } from './Navbar';
export { default as Home } from './Home';
export { default as Footer } from './Footer';
export { default as Contact } from './Contact';
export { default as Body } from './Body';
export { default as Subscribe } from './Subscribe';
```

Then inside App.js, I'll import everything like this.

```
import { 
  Navbar, 
  Home, 
  Footer, 
  Blog, 
  Contact,
  Subscribe } from './components';
```

Everything seems to work for me this way.. Hope that helps.

Comment: i started doing that, it works perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

In React,You need to import a component as follows

```
import {Sidebar} from "pathwherethecomponentexists";
```

you can read more about exports in react [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-importing-exporting/)